# Angular | NgRx Check for null field in an object before putting it in a list of dropdown

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular-forms, dynamic-forms

I have a html dropdown which is sourcing data from an api, the api returns an array of objects [in the component].
The Dropdown uses a field value which is in most objects, but not all.

So it causes, some fields entries to show blank in the dropdown.

```
<div class="col-sm-5">
                    <label>DropDown<label class="field-importance" style="padding-left: 14rem">Required</label></label>
                    <select formControlName="Entry" placeholder="Select Entry" required>
                        <option value="null" disabled="true" [selected]="true" [hidden]="true">Select Entry</option>
                        <option *ngFor="let e of entry" [value]="e.val">{{e.val}}</option>
                    </select>
</div>
```

[image]

Thank you soo much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do a `*ngIf` check for `val` property before using it. Try the following

```html
<div class="col-sm-5">
  <label>DropDown<label class="field-importance" style="padding-left: 14rem">Required</label></label>
  <select formControlName="Entry" placeholder="Select Entry" required>
    <option value="null" disabled="true" [selected]="true" [hidden]="true">Select Entry</option>
    <ng-container *ngFor="let e of entry">
      <ng-container *ngIf="e.val">
        <option [value]="e.val">{{e.val}}</option>
      </ng-container>
    </ng-container>
  </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend filtering out null values from your array in the ts code. So when you are initializing data to the entry variable, do something like this:

```
this.entry = data.filter(x => x.val);
```

Comment: Also as a convention, I would recommend naming array type variables as plural instead of singular. So entries instead of entry.